# Unified Communications & Collaboration for graduation project

Tags: bigdata, data-science, business-intelligence

i don't understand what is Unified Communications & Collaboration ? And what could be help for ?
Does it an interesting subject for a graduation project for a Data engineering student ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not abut programming.

Comment: There a lot of questions in stackoverflow doesn't talk about programming but about another fields

Comment: I agree, but the fact that there are many of them makes them no less off-topic.